# Verify version of a gem with bundler from inside Ruby

Tags: ruby, bundler

Is there a way to verify that I have the latest version of a gem from inside a Ruby program? That is, is there a way to do `bundle outdated #{gemname}` programmatically?

I tried looking at bundler's source code but I couldn't find a straight-forward way. Currently I'm doing this, which is fragile, slow and so inelegant:

```
IO.popen(%w{/usr/bin/env bundle outdated gemname}) do |proc|
  output = proc.readlines.join("\n")
  return output.include?("Your bundle is up to date!")
end
```

Comment: Thank you guys, many answers confirm my findings: there's no API to do this. I picked one based in that it provides a working piece of code to achieve this task.

Comment: I think the answer you picked has some gotchas. There's an `exit 1` which would terminate your program execution. Were you able to get that code to work? I got an error while trying it out.

Comment: They just introduced the `exit 1` between versions 1.2.x and 1.3.x, so now it requires a bit of monkey-patching to work around.

Comment: I've extracted `bundle outdated` into a reusable method without the exit's and the console outputs. I think it should be cleaner than monkey patching "exit" or swapping output stream. See my updated answer for the link to tested code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A way to avoid external execution:

For bundler 1.2.x

```
require 'bundler/cli'

# intercepting $stdout into a StringIO
old_stdout, $stdout = $stdout, StringIO.new 

# running the same code run in the 'bundler outdated' utility
Bundler::CLI.new.outdated('rails')

# storing the output
output = $stdout.string 

# restoring $stdout
$stdout = old_stdout
```

For bundler 1.3.x

```
require 'bundler/cli'
require 'bundler/friendly_errors'

# let's cheat the CLI class with fake exit method
module Bundler
  class CLI 
    desc 'exit', 'fake exit' # this is required by Thor
    def exit(*); end         # simply do nothing
  end 
end

# intercepting $stdout into a StringIO
old_stdout, $stdout = $stdout, StringIO.new 

# running the same code run in the 'bundler outdated' utility
Bundler.with_friendly_errors { Bundler::CLI.start(['outdated', 'rails']) }

# storing the output
output = $stdout.string 

# restoring $stdout
$stdout = old_stdout
```

Comment: I got an error while running this. Also , `outdated` has a sneaky `exit 1` in it. I don't think it can work like this.

Comment: Hmm. True. It works with bundler 1.2.3 and breaks with 1.3.5.

Answer (score 4):

There is no programmatic way to use `outdated` command in bundler, because the code is in a Thor CLI file which prints output to the user. Bundler's tests are also issuing the command to the system and checking the output ([Link to `outdated` tests](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/spec/other/outdated_spec.rb)).

It should be fairly simple to write your own method to mirror what the `outdated` method in cli.rb is doing, though. See the highlighted code here : [Link to outdated method in Bundler source](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb#L398-L451). Remove lines with `Bundler.ui` and return true/false based on the value of `out_count`

**Update**: I've extracted 'bundle outdated' into a reusable method without the console output and the exits. You can find the gist here : [link to gist](https://gist.github.com/emilsoman/5353137). I have tested this on bundler 1.3 and it seems to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is going to end up being the only real way to do it programmatically.  I'm surprised at how poorly-written Bundler is.  No separation of concerns going on at all; the UI code is completely intertwined with the version-checking logic.  It's kind of sad to look at.

Comment: @JimStewart, I'm pretty sure they'll accept a contribution with a few refactors.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle check` list the gems that are out to date, you might want to use it.

Comment: My question is about running it from inside Ruby, programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, sounds like you might want `bundle show` or `gem env`

Answer (score 0):

Disappointing, this looks surprisingly difficult.

There are a couple of [open](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2113) [issues](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2065) in bundler where the official line appears to be:

> At this point in time, there isn't a documented ruby API. 
>   It's something that's on our list, though.

Looking through the bundler source code [cli.rb](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb), it's fairly clear that it's going to be tricky to call from ruby, or reproduce the code in a sensible manner.

Calling methods from CLI will be difficult because they're sprinkled with [calls to exit](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb#L449).

Reproducing the code doesn't look fun either because there is quite a lot of bundler logic in there.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

checking the source code of latest bundler source code

I could come up with this

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb#L398

```
$ irb
1.9.3p327 :001 > require 'bundler'
 => true 
1.9.3p327 :002 > def outdated_gems(gem_name,options={})
1.9.3p327 :003?>   options[:source] ||= 'https://rubygems.org'
1.9.3p327 :004?>   sources = Array(options[:source])
1.9.3p327 :005?>   current_spec= Bundler.load.specs[gem_name].first
1.9.3p327 :006?>   raise "not found in Gemfile" if current_spec.nil?
1.9.3p327 :007?>   definition = Bundler.definition(:gems => [gem_name], :sources => sources)
1.9.3p327 :008?>   options["local"] ? definition.resolve_with_cache! : definition.resolve_remotely!
1.9.3p327 :009?>       active_spec = definition.index[gem_name].sort_by { |b| b.version }
1.9.3p327 :010?>    if !current_spec.version.prerelease? && !options[:pre] && active_spec.size > 1
1.9.3p327 :011?>             active_spec = active_spec.delete_if { |b| b.respond_to?(:version) && b.version.prerelease? }
1.9.3p327 :012?>         end
1.9.3p327 :013?>       active_spec = active_spec.last
1.9.3p327 :014?>       raise "Error" if active_spec.nil?
1.9.3p327 :015?>   outdated = Gem::Version.new(active_spec.version) > Gem::Version.new(current_spec.version)
1.9.3p327 :016?>   {:outdated=>outdated,:current_spec_version=>current_spec.version.to_s,:latest_version=>active_spec.version.to_s}
1.9.3p327 :017?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3p327 :018 > 
1.9.3p327 :019 >   
1.9.3p327 :020 >   
1.9.3p327 :021 >   
1.9.3p327 :022 >   outdated_gems('rake')
 => {:outdated=>true, :current_spec_version=>"10.0.3", :latest_version=>"10.0.4"}
```

This may not work with earlier version of bundler.